# Unchecking a switch depending on user decision

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uilocalnotification, uiswitch

I'm building an app that asks the user for permission to post notifications when the user enables a switch. I'm using this code:

```
- (IBAction)mySwitchValueChanged:(id)sender {
if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]]; // ask the user for permission
}

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(currentUserNotificationSettings)]) { // Check it's iOS 8 and above
    UIUserNotificationSettings *grantedSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
    if (grantedSettings.types != UIUserNotificationTypeNone)
    {
        // Accepted
    } else
    {
        [self.mySwitch setOn:NO]; // Declined
    }
}
}
```

The desired behaviour is as follows:

- User slides switch
- Alert asks for permission
- Code waits for user to decide
- Either does whatever I code where I've put // accepted, or disables the switch.

The current behaviour makes the code run through at once, and doesn't wait for the user to decide. How can I change this to get the desired behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the delegate callbacks you get?

Comment: Read the discussion in the docs for `registerUserNotificationSettings`. It tells you how to handle this.

Comment: @rmaddy reading now. I see the docs tells you this: "If your app displays alerts, play sounds, or badges its icon, you must call this method during your launch cycle to request permission to alert the user in these ways.". But I'm calling this when the user slides a switch which gives much more context to the user as they know what they're "signing up for". Is this allowed?

Comment: Read the second paragraph of the discussion.

Comment: @rmaddy I've read it but I'm not quite sure. The first part of the discussions says "you must call this method during your launch cycle to request permission to alert the user in these ways", while a little further down it says "It is recommended that you call this method before you schedule any local notifications or register with the push notification service."

Comment: You've quoted the 1st and 3rd paragraphs. I'm pointing out the 2nd. Basically, the answer you just accepted is what I meant.

Comment: Oh I see, yeah I was trying to find out where I should call for permission. I understood the handling once the user decides the accept or decline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** This is workaround idea

*Once you call this method :- `[UIApplication sharedApplication]  registerUserNotificationSettings` and user grants push notification for the app, then `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` in AppDelegate get fired,*

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  //call a notification when user granted Push Notifiaction 
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
    postNotificationName:@"PushNotificationSuccess" 
    object:self];

}
```

*So what you have to do, you can call a NSNotification from the mentioned method, to update the UI accordingly.*

```
- (void)updateUIOnNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{

            // Accepted
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Call the below method in your else part and remove the line
    //[self.mySwitch setOn:NO];

    -(void)Showalert{
    UIAlertview*Temp=[[UIAlertview alloc]initWithTitle:@"Need Permission to Send Notifications" message:@"The App Wants The Permission to Work Properly!\nPermit The App in Notification settings"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [Temp show];        
    }
    #pragma mark Alertview delegate method
    - (void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    //Remove the Below line From Else part of your code
      [self.mySwitch setOn:NO];
    }
```